# Need some advise on Silverlight template/style reuse strategy

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, expression-sketchflow

I'm an absolute Silverlight noob that is confused by the help file. Here is what I want:

I would like to use Expression Blend for the creation of mockups using Sketchflow. I want to create a set of controls that have my companies' look & feel applied to them and be able to easily reuse then across projects, preferably by simply dragging and dropping them onto a canvas. In addition, it would be great if a control, screen or even an entire project can switch skin/theme, for example one theme for intranet and one theme for internet.

With so many ways in Blend to reuse things, I am wondering what the best strategy is for my situation? Should I create style or templates? User controls or custom controls? How do I easily share controls and themes across projects?

I ask for a lot but I'm finding this stuff to not be as straightforward as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good introductory articles to blend written by a collegue of mine http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=7003572

Alternatively if you are looking for training assistance, you can give my company a call  www.imeta.co.uk